# When are ranges::views calculated at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3

The [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html) library allows the use of `views`, which enable lazy operations on data. From what I know, lazy operations are only possible when a function is evaluated at compile time, but to achieve a compile time calculation, the code must be in a context where a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) is possible.

I tried out to repeat a number by using the function `ranges::view::repeat_n(0,5)` and store it as a `constexpr` variable, but the compiler error points out that the function is not a `constexpr`:

```
error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘ranges::repeat_n_view<Val> ranges::views::repeat_n_fn::operator()(Val, std::ptrdiff_t) const requires  copy_constructible<Val> [with Val = int; std::ptrdiff_t = long int]’
   16 |     constexpr auto rng_view = ranges::view::repeat_n(0,5);
```

Does that mean, that views aren't always constant expression ?

Here my main code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <range/v3/view/empty.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/repeat_n.hpp>
#include <range/v3/algorithm/for_each.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/cycle.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/take.hpp>
using std::cout;

int main() {

    constexpr auto rng = ranges::view::empty<int>; //OK

    //repeat the number zero five times
    constexpr auto rng_view = ranges::view::repeat_n(0,5);//ERROR:Call to non-`constexpr` function
    std::cout << rng_view << std::endl;

    return 0;
{
```

Is there any possibility to store all `views` as `constexpr` values to ensure a compile time calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> lazy operations are only possible when a function is evaluated at compile time

Lazy operations are operations which compute a result on-demand rather than immediately upon executing the expression which appears to compute that result. For example, a transform view applied to some container *appears* to immediately apply the transform operation to every element of the view. But in reality, it only applies the transformation when you attempt to *access* the value from the view.

This process has nothing to do specifically with compile-time execution.

Comment: I always assumed that the "lazy" operation is done at compile time, because the compile can optimize code such that is only evaluates code blocks that are used (constexpr if) or using expression template programming your are able to calculate sums or multiplications over matrices only when a specific position `i` is requested.

Comment: I hoped to use ranges to avoid expression template programming for matrix multiplication or contraction operations. From what i know, expression templates do that job at compile time to save memory by not creating temporary objects and optimize the code. If not all views are constant expression, that would mean, expression templates may be superior if you want to calculate at compile time??

Comment: Firstly, let's get some language straight: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation. You wrote "lazy operation" and I assumed you meant lazy evaluation as per the given link. Lazy evaluation kind-of contradicts compile-time evaluation, because one tries to perform heavy computations as late as possible while the other tries to do it as early as possible. However, they don't contradict strictly and they can actually be combined.

Answer (score 3):

Right, views are not always constant expressions. Some (like e.g. the empty one, as you discovered) can be declared as constant expressions. The other one, `repeat_n()`, is implemented in a way that doesn't allow it to be a constant expression.

However, that just answers your explicit question. More important is that your assumption that "lazy operations are only possible when a function is evaluated at compile time" seems wrong to me and with that your conclusions tumble as well. I don't exclude that we just mean different things with this, so maybe you want to clarify.

However, to me, lazy evaluation only requires that the result doesn't depend on any external state, so that it simply doesn't matter when something is computed. In above case, `repeat_n()` doesn't have to generate the sequence of values until they are actually used. This is a bad example, because any sane implementation would never generate more than a single value, but that's beside the point. There is no implied requirement in lazy evaluation that forces this to be a constant expression and also nothing that prevents it from being one.

Comment: i wrote a small comment under Nicol Bolas post. Maybe it explains what i thought about lazy evaluation and why i tried to use ranges.